# Pdf file not sent with phpmailer

Tags: php, email, pdf, phpmailer, sendmail

i'm using phpmailer but i can't send a pdf with $mail->addAttachment() method.that't what i have tried.

```
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->addAttachment('file.pdf',' CV');

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
//header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: Whats the error you get from mail function?

Comment: Why don't you try checking the return value from addAttachment() to make sure it's working before sending?

Comment: This is the error i get. Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpMail\mailerClass\class.smtp.php on line 937